# JavaScript sort ascending or descending order values in object base on sub object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have product object. every product i have price sub object. Inside price object can have multiple values. I want to sort price object base on original_price and then entire product object base on price.

e.g

```
[
 {product: 1, 
  price[
   {id: 1, original_price: 18},
   {id: 2, original_price: 10}
 ]
},
{product: 2, 
  price[
   {id: 1, original_price: 12},
   {id: 2, original_price: 15},
   {id:3, original_price: 5}
  ]
 }
]
```

**After sort**

```
[
 {product: 2,
    price[
      {id: 3, original_price: 5},
      {id: 1, original_price: 12},
      {id: 2, original_price: 15}
     ]
  }
  {product: 1,
      price[
        {id: 2, original_price: 10},
        {id: 1, original_price: 18}
       ]
   }
]
```

can someone help me to fix this?

**Need to sort both ways (ascending or descending)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the assumption that you will be sorting based on `product` and `original_price`, you could do this.

```
function sortAscendingPrice(a, b) {
    return a.original_price - b.original_price;
}

function sortDescendingPrice(a, b) {
    return b.original_price - a.original_price;
}

function sortAscendingProduct(a, b) {
    return a.product - b.product;
}

function sortDescendingProduct(a, b) {
    return b.product - a.product;
}

const data = [
    {
        product: 1,
        price: [
            {id: 1, original_price: 18},
            {id: 2, original_price: 10}
        ]
    },
    {
        product: 2,
        price: [
            {id: 1, original_price: 12},
            {id: 2, original_price: 15},
            {id:3, original_price: 5}
        ]
    }
];

const sortedData = data
    .map(el => {
        return {
            product: el.product,
            price: el.price.sort(sortAscendingPrice)
        };
    })
    .sort(sortDescendingProduct);
```

This will sort your data the way that you are expecting it to be sorted. If you wanted to sort ascending/descending you would just switch out the function that you pass in to your sort when needed. I've provided both ascending and descending functions in this example even though they are not all being used.

More information about sorting arrays can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: small help if one product don't have any prices inside how to skip that record during sort. (Like if no prices product come at top or last base on sort)? @Chris

Comment: You would need to add additional logic within the sort function for that and do additional checks. If you look at the documentation that I linked for array.sort() you will see that you can return -1, 1, or 0 to sort an item a specific way.